# Variable Undefined in Directive with isolated scope

Tags: angularjs

I created a directive with isolated scope. `selectedcontractguid` is passed to the directive via html.

when I console.log `$scope` in directive, it shows me selectedcontractguid along with correct guid.

But when I try to access `$scope.selectedcontractguid` in directive controller, it logs undefined.

Anyone know why? please take a look at following example.

```
<instalments-box selectedcontractguid="instalment.contract.guid"> </instalments-box>

angular.module('app')
.directive('instalmentsBox', ['InstalmentService', function(InstalmentService) {
    return {
        templateUrl:'scripts/directives/contracts/instalments-box.html?v='+window.app_version,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            selectedcontractguid: '='
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            console.log($scope.selectedcontractguid);
        }
    }
}]);
```

[image: console.log output]

Comment: how are you setting `instalment.contract.guid` in the controller?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one may be $watch help you out :

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('instalmentsBox'['InstalmentService', function(InstalmentService) {
    return {
     templateUrl:'scripts/directives/contracts/instalments-box.html?v='+window.app_version,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            selectedcontractguid: '=selectedcontractguid'
        },
        controller: function($scope,$watch) {
          $scope.$watch('selectedcontractguid', function (watch) {
            console.log(watch);
          })
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me, can you please explain a bit. Why do I have to watch it?

Comment: sometimes in angularJs `$scope` creates multiple instances of an object so `$watch` keep watch on all that instances. hence many times you need to watch on objects in your directives